# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <ima> does not exist

Tags: alias, keytool, jks, java

I am trying to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) from a public RSA key in the earlier generated keystore using the Java Keytool utility:

```
keytool -certreq -alias ima -file \
example_cert_req.csr -keystore example_keystore.jks \
-storepass example_password
```

It raises this error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <ima> does not exist
```

How can I fix this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First you should convert csr file to crt with key. And then import crt to jks keystore.

```
openssl x509 -req -in example_cert_req.csr -signkey privateKey.key -out certificate.crt
keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore example_keystore.jks -alias "ima"
```